# MySQL Finding index size for compound unique indexes

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, unique-constraint

I'm using following query to get index and data sizes for tables in database. But unfortunately it doesn't show index size for compound unique indexes. How can i get index sizes for compound unique indexes?

Here is my query;

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table",
TABLE_ROWS AS "Rows",
CONCAT((FORMAT((DATA_LENGTH) / POWER(1024,2),2)), ' Mb') AS "Data Size",
CONCAT((FORMAT((INDEX_LENGTH) / POWER(1024,2),2)), ' Mb') AS "Index Size",
CONCAT((FORMAT((DATA_LENGTH+ INDEX_LENGTH) / POWER(1024,2),2)), ' Mb') AS "Total Size",
TRIM(TRAILING ', ' FROM CONCAT_WS(', ', ENGINE, TABLE_COLLATION, CREATE_OPTIONS)) AS "Type"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema = "my_database_name_here"
```

Comment: `Index Size` contains total sum of sizes of all (non-primary) indexes defined on the table, there is no simple way to get the size of one specific index afaik

Comment: "non-primary" for InnoDB at least, in MyISAM even the primary key will be counted in the index size.

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL (not Percona), see if this table gives you what you want:

```
mysql.INNODB_INDEX_STATS
```

Sorry, but it is not easy to tease out the specific data you asked about.